# Algorithm to generate small but valid variable names for Javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, algorithm

I am working on a component framework in PHP that generates Javascript from server side and render it on client. Furthermore in Ajax communication the **ids** and value of components is transfered from client side to server. These ids are meaningful and large in length.

I would like to replace these bigs ids/variables with smaller names like **_, _1, _2,_a, or _A** So i need an algorithm that can generate next valid Javascript variable name such that whenever i call get_next_id function it gives me next unique variable name. Currently I checked **uniqid** in PHP but value returned is quite big.

Is there any way or algorithm to generate these type of names in PHP? **Please note that the function must fisrt start from smallest possible variable name and then to higher order.**

Comment: Why do you care about size of names? They don't matter a lot. If bandwidth is an issue, compress your data (i.e. your script).

Comment: You can always use part of the uniqid: `echo substr( uniqid('', true), -6 );`

Comment: ( n ).toString(36) gives you small ids with numbers and letters; set n to count and you have incremental ids.

Answer (score 2):

You can increment alphabetic characters in php:

```
for( $x = 'a'; $x!='z'; $x++) {
    echo "$x\n";
  }
```

Comment: how much ids I can get with this? 26

Comment: @asim-ishaq you can do 'aa' or also mix it with numbers to get a lot more.

Comment: @asim-ishaq prepend a '_'?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the class below may do the trick. One could easily extend it to use more characters. I've used only lower case characters for simplicity.

```
class IdGenerator {
  function IdGenerator() {
    $this->id = 0;
  }

  function getId() {
   $ret = $this->getStringForId($this->id);
   $this->id += 1;
   return $ret;
  }

  function getStringForId($id) {
    $res = '';
    do {
      $res = chr( ord('a') + ($id % 26) ) . $res;
      $id = (int)($id / 26) - 1;
    } while ($id >= 0);
    return '_' . $res;
  }
}
```

The class just keeps a simple counter of how many ids it has generated so far. The function `getStringForId` generates a unique, minimal string for each index it is given.

If you run this test

```
$g = new IdGenerator();
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
  echo $g->getId() . "\n";
}
```

You'll get

_a
  _b
  _c
  ...
  _y
  _z
  _aa
  _ab
  _ac
  _ad